# Sitecore WFFM - Preload form with data from Session

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm trying to create a WFFM form in Sitecore to edit the current user's profile, which is stored in the Session (different from the `Sitecore.Context.User.Profile`). To this end, I'm looking for a way to preload the form's fields with the profile data from the Session.

Can this be done? I'm using Sitecore CMS 6.5 and WFFM 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the solution to the problem was a little more involved. First of all, I moved all profile information from the session to `Sitecore.Context.User`'s `Profile`. To do this, a custom user profile class had to be implemented. Using this approach, I know needed to preload the form fields from this custom profile instead of the session.

To do this, I created a folder under the content tree, called "Profile Variables", which represented the custom profile properties that needed to be read, in dot notation. For example: `{ DisplayName: "Home Telephone", Value: "ContactDetails.HomeTelephone" }`.

Finally, I created a custom WFFM field type, based on the Single Line Text field type, which takes one more property, `PreloadField`, taking values from the "Profile Variables" node, and on the custom field type's `OnInit` I read from the context user's profile using reflection the value of the property stored in `PreloadField` and set the text field's `Text` property to that value.

Hope this helps somebody else in search for something similar.

Answer (score 3):

WFFM can't do this out of the box. We've choosen another approach to solve the problem. In the form rendering under `/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Form` you have the field `Parameters` where you can add a the parameter `FormTemplate` with a custom user control for rendering the form:

```
FormTemplate=/sitecore modules/web/Web Forms for Marketers/Control/CustomSimpleFormAscx.ascx
```

In this user control we loop through each field and set the value for the input field based on the user's custom properties. Of course you could enhance this to other fields like select's etc. Here is some example code:

```
public partial class CustomSimpleFormAscx : SitecoreSimpleFormAscx
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        FillInUserData(this.FieldContainer);
    }

    private void FillInUserData(System.Web.UI.Control control)
    {
        foreach (System.Web.UI.Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            if (child is BaseControl)
            {
                if (child is InputControl)
                {
                    InputControl field = (InputControl)child;
                    field.Text = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetCustomProperty(field.ControlName);
                }
            }

            FillInUserData(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you decompile the `FormRenderer` WebControl and build your own that does this. That is the standard presentation control to render forms via the WFFM module.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, it seems decompiling was the way to go after all, but not this class. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do something similar.  In the 2.3 version of WFFM there are some rule actions that allow you do set the value of a field from the user profile.

See Actions: use the default value from user profile specific field option until Rules when you select a form field.

You can use full name, email, comment, or any other custom property.

The one field that's not included is the UserName field.  You can write a custom action return the user name field.